# Are there some supervised machine learning methods that learn to rank the features?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, ranking, supervised-learning

For example, given training data/features
$$
\mathbf{X}^{(1)} = \{\mathbf{x}_1^{(1)}, \mathbf{x}_2^{(1)}, \mathbf{x}_3^{(1)}, \dots, \mathbf{x}_{l_1}^{(1)}\} \\
\mathbf{X}^{(2)} = \{\mathbf{x}_1^{(2)}, \mathbf{x}_2^{(2)}, \mathbf{x}_3^{(2)}, \dots, \mathbf{x}_{l_2}^{(2)}\} \\
\dots \\
\mathbf{X}^{(n)} = \{\mathbf{x}_1^{(n)}, \mathbf{x}_2^{(n)}, \mathbf{x}_3^{(n)}, \dots, \mathbf{x}_{l_n}^{(n)}\}
$$
In this case,
each sample is a matrix/set that contains multiple vectors (the exact number of vectors could be different, denoted as $l_i$). Each vector has $k$ values, i.e., $\mathbf{x}_i^{(j)} \in \mathcal{R}^k$. These values are aligned features (i.e., the first value of $\mathbf{x}_i^{(j)}$ denotes the same thing as the first value of $\mathbf{x}_p^{(q)}$ denotes).

We hope to train a machine learning model $f: \mathcal{R}^k \rightarrow \mathcal{R}$ that takes in this feature vector and outputs a scalar that can be used to rank these vectors.

And we hope to train this model in a supervised manner with information such as:
$$
y_2^{(1)} > y_7^{(1)} > y_9^{(1)} > \dots, > y_{3}^{(1)} \\
y_4^{(2)} > y_2^{(2)} > y_1^{(2)} > \dots, > y_{6}^{(2)} \\
\dots \\
y_4^{(n)} > y_5^{(n)} > y_3^{(n)} > \dots, > y_{2}^{(n)} \\
$$

Therefore, when there are future test data (each sample is a set of vectors) the model can learn to rank these vectors.

I wonder if there are machine learning model can suit this need. Or where I can start to look at techniques like this?

Comment: I don’t see what this has to do with ranking _features_. This seems to be asking whether learning to rank exists; am I missing something here that keeps this outside that paradigm?

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy Thanks. I think "learning to rank" mainly refers to rank the samples. Or probably I should consider each "feature vector" in my post as a sample.